# In blender 2.8 how do you make a local instance of an object in use by multiple scenes?

Tags: workflow

I have created a new scene using linked copies.

[image: Scene / linked copies]

Now I need to make a few of the object single-user so there is a separate object in the original and in the new scene.

Back in 2.79 there was a button for that:

[image: the single-user copy button]

Blender 2.8 seems to lack that button.  How do I make a single-user copy of the object?

Do not confuse the object with the object data (like mesh or curve).  The mesh panel does have the button, but I need to make the *object* single user and that panel is missing the necessary button.

Based on some of the comments I have concluded I am going to have to get horribly detailed, because what other people are experiencing does not match how my stock blender 2.80 behaves:

Start with the default scene:
[image: default scene]

Add a cone:
[image: add a cone]

duplicate the scene
[image: duplicate the scene]

and let's change the outliner to let us see both scenes
[image: two scenes appear in outliner]
Notice that my Object panel lacks the button that would allow me to make the object single-user.

Let's rotate the cone by 180.
[image: upside-down cone]

Oh no!  It affected the original scene
[image: cone is upside-down in original scene now.]

And if we delete the object from one scene, it disappears from both scenes.  **WHAT!**
[image: deletion affects both scenes]

Undo that deletion.
Let's use the Object>Relations>Make Single User>Selected Objects .
[image: make single user]

Oh no.  Now both scenes have Cone.001 and Cone has disappeared.
[image: both scenes now have Cone.001]

How do I change my workflow to accomplish the mission of having two scenes with some objects in common , and other objects have single-user versions of objects from the original scene?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the object linked? I get the same button in 2.8 and if I press it I get a single user.

Comment: I am confident the object is linked.  I can change the location and it is moved in the other scene.  I wish I could see a screenshot of your button (www.pasteall.org?).

Comment: http://pasteall.org/pic/63c463106c8f07ca9c6d62f559736713

Comment: Jackdaw, that button just does not show up in my version of blender 2.8-linux-glibc217-x86_64 .  Also, when I add a sphere to one scene, it appears in both scenes.  Something fishy is going on.

Comment: I am beginning to wonder if Collections are some kind of datablock that is being shared between scenes, and there is no panel to manage the Collection that would allow me to make a single-user instance of the Collection.

Comment: Hi @MutantBob. I have basically the same issue. Did you ever report that? I can't find the bug report. Thanks

Comment: I eventually reported it as https://developer.blender.org/T40906 and as of 2019-Dec they are treating it as a feature request (which is reasonable, if inconvenient for me).

Answer (score 2):

Make New Scene with Copy Settings. Go to your first scene and link all necessary object to newly created scene. Go to your new scene and now Make Single User under Object->Relations works as expected.

Comment: This is the best workaround, but I'm still in search of an explanation of what's going on with a Linked Copy of the scene.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in 2.9x version too. Using linked copy will cause the collections linked to both scenes, make single user works with the objects that ONLY in scene collection.

I found out that using "Instance to scene" option to instance a collection from the original scene to a new scene allows you to change the Loc, rot and scale without affecting the original objects.

Make sure you're in the scene you want the instance be when clicking the "Instance to scene" button.
It will create a empty for the instance and you can center it by using set origin.

Still figuring out the workflow with a complex scene, also the "linked copy" feature still makes me confuse.
[image: Instance to scene]

Answer (score -1):

at the top of the screen, click **object - relations** and there are two options there that should do what you want:  **make local** or **make single user**.

hope this helps

Comment: make local does not work.  make single user does work.  Edit your answer to explain the difference between the two and it will be suitable as an answer.

Comment: originally I didn't know whether they would work, I just assumed one of them would because it seemed to make sense.  Now I tested it and **make local - all** worked great.  Did you try that?

Comment: Make Local / All seems to have no effect in version 2.80 that I have installed.  I'm also anticipating if they ever fix it, it would make local copies of the mesh and materials too (which is very much *not* what I want).

Comment: That's to bad.  I don't know too much about linking, so I guess I can't help you.  Just so you know, I'm using Blender 2.80 stable.

Comment: after some more testing, it appears that even Make Single User does NOT work.   I edited the question to include a lot of screenshots to illustrate.

Comment: blender 2.82. The only way to do this is make a full copy new scene. Both make local and single user doesn't work.