# In blender 2.8 how do I make a scene-local instance of a collection after creating a linked scene?

Tags: collections

I first discovered some workflow shortcomings of blender 2.8 when I asked "
[In blender 2.8 how do you make a local instance of an object in use by multiple scenes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148173/in-blender-2-8-how-do-you-make-a-local-instance-of-an-object-in-use-by-multiple?noredirect=1#comment253278_148173) "

Now that I understand collections a *little* bit more, I can describe what is going on.

When you use New Scene>Linked Copy you end up with linked instances of all your objects, but for objects inside a collection (which is the case for the camera, cube, and light in the default scene) you do not have access to a "make local" button in the object panel.  That is because there is only one User of the object:  Its Collection.

The collection has been linked to both scenes and *that* is the "problem".

I can not find a way to make a scene-local copy of that collection.

- Right-clicking on the collection in the outliner brings up a menu with no obvious solutions
- I have not found a tab to manage the properties of a Collection (which would be the natural place for a Make Local button.)  This makes collections like second-class citizens compared to objects, meshes, materials, etc.

When I imagine a Make Local operation for collections the obvious (to me) functionality would

- create a new collection which has links to every object in the original collection (objects, subcollections, other things I have not yet realized can belong to collections)
- link this newly created collection to the same container of the original collection (which might be the scene, or might be a parent collection)
- unlink the original collection from its parent in this context, leaving the fresh copy as its replacement.

A complication that I only realized while creating the list above: if the collection is a subcollection (its parent is a collection instead of a scene), it won't immediately become scene-local, because the scene still has the shared parent collection.  (maybe another operator we need for this is "make local recurse up")

What am I overlooking?  Where is the button/menu that will let me make a scene-local copy of a collection?

Comment: You are overlooking, that when you RMB click on the collection and choose *ID data > Make Single User* the info bar shows: [not implemented yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tapS2.png), because this feature seems to be not implemented yet. Meanwhile, can't you use *New Scene > Link Object Data*?

Comment: That operation does not appear on the menu when right-clicking on the menu in the Scenes mode of the Outliner.  It does appear in the View Layer mode (which I had not looked at).  It is not clear to me why the two views have different menus for the collections object, but maybe it is a philosophical difference.

Comment: Using New Scene > Link Object Data is NOT what I want.  I want most *objects* to be shared between the two scenes, and only a few to be scene-local.