# Scene Management Linked Copy can't make Local Objects Issue

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, scene, collections

I would like to use the Scene Management tool in Blender associated with the Powerful Video Sequence Editor in order to create a pre visualization Sequence.

The idea is simply to have data that will remain linked from one scene to another, like the set, ground, materials and most of the lighting. Then, having the option to make a few assets local to do different camera/characters/props movement or even change the intensity of specific lighting from one scene to another. This mixed with the *Video Sequence Editor* where we can call each scene separately to reorder them or create a great editorial would make it similar to the Unreal Sequencer.

It seems that all the options are there but the make local seems to not be working properly once a scene is linked? It seems to keep the link between scenes no matter what I try.

- Right click make local
- Ctrl A Make Instance Real
- Relations Make Local or Make Single users object data/object animation

I have a Basic scene showing what I would like to achieve
Also just referencing that [other post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150957)